# Word for something that is barely stable

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Something which will destabilize very easily.

> The Birlings (an inspector calls) were a ____ family.

Comment: Maybe "fragile", "brittle"?

Comment: *tempestuous* works well for a lot of families, though this question is very low on the sort of background color that suggests one word might be better than another.

Comment: Volatile fits well

Answer (score 3):

**precarious**

dependent on circumstances beyond one's control; uncertain; unstable; insecure:
a precarious livelihood.

dependent on the will or pleasure of another; liable to be withdrawn or lost at the will of another:

**volatile**

changeable; mercurial; flighty:
a volatile disposition.

www.dictionary.com

Answer (score 1):

Does the word "unstable" not suit your needs?

> prone to change, fail, or give way; not stable. —[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/unstable)

Comment: Can you edit to mention/link to where you got this definition from?

Comment: Is this right? @Laurel

Comment: Almost. Google gets its definitions from one of the two online Oxford dictionaries, in this case the US version. (See [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11484/191178).)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [labile](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/labile?s=t)

> adjective
>
> ```
> apt or likely to change.
> ```

The family might be prone to [labile moods](https://psychcentral.com/encyclopedia/labile-mood/)
From Psychcentral:

> Marked fluctuation of mood; can be a symptom of a disorder such as
>   schizophrenia.
>
> Example: A woman seeks help for “ups and downs” lasting days or weeks;
>   she can’t seem to keep her emotions on an even keel.